# Is it okay to link to your own image/gallery if it's semi-related to a question or answer?

Tags: discussion, links

Is is acceptable to link to an image/gallery if the relationship to the question or post is tangential at best?

Example, [I asked a question about chimping](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/961/why-is-chimping-a-derogatory-term), and mentioned that while I always review the histogram, I've only once shown off an image via the LCD. Would a posting URL to the image be appropriate? Or is it better to wait till someone asks what that image is, and post the url in the comment?

Comment: Link to the question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/961/why-is-chimping-a-derogatory-term

Can somebody with enough rep (or author) put this link into the question, please?

Comment: This is closely related to another question, see the answer here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100/is-is-acceptable-to-deep-link-to-external-sites-to-support-an-answer/119#119

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that case, the image seems irrelevant to the question so I would vote no.

I would only post the image (or link to the image) if the image has some content related to the question or the answer.

OTOH, you should add a link to your gallery to your [bio](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/170/alan).